# IE : Blocks website that has a certificate's CN different from hostname

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl-certificate

May I know what is the settings on IE that blocks website with certificate CN different from hostname?

For example I have a website myhostname but my certificate CN is NotMyHostName. Some IE will blocks it and display 404, so I suspect is related to a security setting.

May I know what is that particular security setting?

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting for that. Verifying that the certificate matches the website visited is a basic security requirement for TLS and HTTPS. If you could turn it off, then the whole "certificate" thing would become completely useless, since could buy a legitimate certificate for somerandomsite.foo.com and impersonate *any* website with it.

See [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) section [3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1), which requires either a hostname check or a specific-certificate check, like the "security exceptions" in Firefox. Since IE doesn't support such "exceptions", it has to always check the CN and/or subjectAltName.

If you want to use the same certificate for multiple sites, list all of them in subjectAltName. The certificate must still match the website, but the CN will be ignored if subjectAltName has DNS names in it.

Comment: My user will get a 404 on his IE if he access the page, but he can access it using Firefox.

Comment: @user4127 Fix the certificate or tell the user the correct hostname to use. Alternatively, don't use SSL and just use HTTP.

Comment: @user4127: How did you determine that the 404 is at all related to the certificates? (In fact, are you sure it's a 404 error? Have you checked the web server's logs?)

Comment: looks like a 404 to me, yes I rectify the issue on the server but I am trying to replicate it to have a better understanding.